# Should the WebUI be just a client for my service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, architecture

Our product has two interfaces: a web interface (ASP.NET) and a service interface (WCF).

What is the correct way of connecting them to the business logic? Should the WebUI be just a client for the WCF service (see diagrams below)?

a. WebUI and WCF separated:

```
User1 -> ASP.NET -/-> Business Layer
User2 -> WCF ----/
```

b. WebUI is just a client of the service

```
User1 -> ASP.NET -/-> WCF -> Business Layer
User2 -----------/
```

Answer (score 1):

If your service exposes absolutely everything that your Web Application needs to do, then why not use it!? ... If this service is going to be given to clients or similar, using it yourself is a great way to test/make sure it does everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would encapsulate the Business Logic in a common DLL that both services will use.

In the service(IIS/WCF) handle only communication/protocol/serialization etc ....

This way it's easier to implement and performance is better.

Answer (score 0):

This also depends on the architecture of your client. If you are using something like MVC, you may have the necessity to create large amounts of ViewModels. If your WCF services are granular, it may make sense to make the services return strongly typed DTO objects. If you share the DLL containing the service contracts with your client, you will be able to use the DTOs contained in the service responses as ViewModels. You get the advantage of scaling your UI application and your business logic middle ware differently by decoupling them in this way.